# All Build and Release Definition Export At Once?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, build-definition

Is there a way to export all Build and/or Release Definitions at once in Azure DevOps, instead of doing it one by one ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by calling Azure DevOps Pipelines REST API. Start by query all build and release definitions, and iterate on each of the definitions to get the JSON detail of the definition.

But if your build is using YAML file, then the build definition will only container definition of where to search the YAML file and also the variable and trigger settings.